# Separation of mathematics and metamathematics

Tags: soft-question, meta-math

I recall reading that it's important to separate mathematics and metamathematics. What exactly does this mean, and why is it so?

I understand that this question may make no sense without more context, but I've been curious about this for a while and can't seem to find where I originally read that.

Comment: For example, it is usually important to distinguish between the meta-natural numbers $0, 1, 2, \ldots$ and the elements in a model of first-order arithmetic you happen to be analysing...

Comment: @Blue: Can you mention the context in which you read this?

Comment: @KartikAudhkhasi: Unfortunately, I can't. I read this a couple years ago, so I forgot the source. It didn't turn up anything in a Google search, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metamathematics is a branch of mathematics, so the assertion does not really make sense. It is certainly important not to confuse a **formal system** with the mathematical tools and ideas used to look into properties of the formal system, or formal systems in general.

Comment: Thanks. While I'll probably never know for sure, that seems like a plausible explanation of what the author of whatever I was reading may have meant